# Converting/Porting Console Project to Formless App in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have very little knowledge about C/C++ but I would like to compile a C++ console project to a regular Windows application. So at the end the app has NO forms at all and only executes the code. Here is the code I have from a ufasoft miner:

```
/*###########################################################################################################################
# Copyright (c) 1997-2012 Ufasoft   http://ufasoft.com   mailto:support@ufasoft.com                                         #
#                                                                                                                           #
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License #
# as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option) any later version.                    #                                                          #
#                                                                                                                           #
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied        #
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.     #
#                                                                                                                           #
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program;                                #
# If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>                                                                                #
###########################################################################################################################*/

#include <el/ext.h>

using namespace Ext;

#undef main
#undef wmain

extern "C" int __cdecl _my_wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[], wchar_t *envp[]);
extern "C" int __cdecl _my_main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]);


int _cdecl ext_main(int argc, argv_char_t *argv[], argv_char_t *envp[]) {
#if UCFG_WCE
    RegistryKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Drivers\\Console").SetValue("OutputTo", 0);
#endif

    atexit(MainOnExit);

#if UCFG_ARGV_UNICODE
    return _my_wmain(argc, argv, envp);
#else
    return _my_main(argc, argv, envp);
#endif
}

#if UCFG_WCE
#   if UCFG_ARGV_UNICODE
#       pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:mainWCRTStartup")
#   else
#       pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:mainACRTStartup")
#   endif
#endif
```

How can I convert this to a regular windows app?
I already changed the SubSystem to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS).
Then I changed the EntryPoint in ProjectSettings to ext_main.
I also have to make sure that the functions gets the CMDCommandLine cause the APP needs to read the parameters.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Every program compiled and "built" by Visual Studio *is* native to the Windows OS.

Comment: Thanks I actually meant without console or forms.

Comment: You mean you want to convert a console app to a WinForms app?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal not quite to a WinForms App. It should be formless.

Comment: I don't understand. The console application *is* a "regular Windows application". Do you want to simply *hide* the console window?

Comment: Hiding the console can be done with ShowWindow and the SW_HIDE def. I would like to set a new entry point but I also need the parameter that are passed to the .exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WinMain`:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    return 0;
}
```

And set the entry point on `Project Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point` to `WinMain`.

And also `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`, but you've already done that.

Comment: I get this LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Comment: It is :/ I checked it myself.

Comment: Have you deleted the old `main`? Because this error occurs when you have a console-type entry-point and try to compile using subsystem `Windows`.

Comment: To make sure all your settings are right, reproduce the steps of creating a new empty project: `New Project -> Win32 Project -> Next`, select `Windows Application` and `Empty project`, click `Finish`. Create a new CPP File called `main.cpp`, and reproduce the steps on my answer. Here it is working fine. I'm sure there's something you are forgetting there.

Comment: it works now but I need to convert the arguments too. How could I do that?

Comment: You can parse `lpCmdLine` or you can use `__argc` and `__argv`, for example: `MessageBox(NULL, __argv[1], "", MB_OK);` will print the first argument.